# Is using Django MondgoDB Engine considered mainstream

Tags: django

I'm totally new to Python and Django - just getting started with both.
I wanted to see how I could work with MongoDB, while using Django framework.
I came across this site:  https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ - seems like a reasonable way of doing non-rel
I'd like to ask experienced Django developers: is using Django MongoDB Engine considered "mainstream" for connecting Django apps to a non-relational backend, or is there a different, more widely used / better supported alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to more widely and used I personally do not think so.

There is Flask, but Django really does everything it does plus a little bit more.

What is the problem with mainstream if it is proven to work?

I would strongly recommend using Django, specially if you interact a lot with databases. It's migration system is the best out there.

If your project is rather small and does not need all those nice features I would recomend Flask instead.

Comment: I do want to use Django, but I would like to use MongoDB instead or Sqlite or MySQL. It was my impression, that Django MongoDB Engine just serves as a backend translation, but the rest is a standard Django. Is that not the case?

Comment: That is actually the case yes :)